# Trying to understand a singleton pattern in Objective-C (RestKit)

Tags: objective-c, design-patterns, singleton, restkit

I am using a iOS library called Restkit, which automatically maps remote objects to local objects. You do that by creating a mapping using KVC pattern, and then loading with the mapping.

While I understand how it works, I don't understand why some parts are implemented in certain ways. For example it uses a singleton pattern where you create an instance of **RKObjectMapping** like below:

```
RKObjectMapping* articleMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[Article class]];
[articleMapping mapKeyPath:@"title" toAttribute:@"title"];
[articleMapping mapKeyPath:@"body" toAttribute:@"body"];
[articleMapping mapKeyPath:@"author" toAttribute:@"author"];
[articleMapping mapKeyPath:@"publication_date" toAttribute:@"publicationDate"];
```

However, when it comes time to actually use it, you access the manager by calling **sharedManager** of the class RKObjectManager, like following:

```
[[RKObjectManager sharedManager].mappingProvider setMapping:articleMapping
                                                 forKeyPath:@"articles"];

[[RKObjectManager sharedManager] loadObjectsAtResourcePath:@"/articles"
                                                  delegate:self];
```

What I don't understand is, why even bother instantiating the class as **articleMapping**, when you will just access it using a class method/variable like **sharedManager**? Why not do something like:

```
[RKObjectMapping initWithClass:[Article class]];
```

I am a newbie so think there would be a good reason for taking this pattern that I am not aware of. Anyone know or understand why this would be implemented in this way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When an object needs to access data associated to itself, it uses instance variables (ivars) to store that data. However, **instance** variables are part of a specific instance of the class and not the class itself - from a class method, they cannot be accessed. So, when the manager class you're talking about was to store/access its private data, it uses a shared instance (singleton) to create instance variables. If it was used only as a class, it had to store its private data in global variables, which is considered bad practice in C.

Also, if you look closely, the `RKObjectManager` class has properties. In Objective-C, properties are always backed by an underlying instance variable (be it created at runtime, dynamically, or at compile time, in a declared manner) - that's why classes can't have properties, and that's why a singleton (an actual instance of a class) is needed.

Example without singleton (ugly):

```
static int uglyGlobalVar;

@interface UglyClass: NSObject

+ (void)storeData:(int)data;

@end

@implementation UglyClass: NSObject

+ (void)storeData:(int)data
{
    uglyGlobalVar = data;
}

@end
```

Example with singleton (much better):

```
@interface GoodClass: NSObject {
    int data;
}

+ (GoodClass *)sharedInstance;

@property (nonatomic, assign) int data;

@end

@implementation GoodClass: NSObject

@syntehsize data;

// also implement sharedInstance here

@end

// then this class is usable as:
[GoodClass sharedInstance].data = 1337;
```

Comment: Thank you for the great answer. But I think this answers half of my question. The other half is: Why instantiate the mapping as "articleMapping" at all (First line in the first box) when you will later access it using sharedManager (Second box). I was wondering why one would not implement a class method like "[RKObjectMapping initWithClass:[Article class]];" to create the sharedManager singleton and use sharedManager for everything that comes after (Third box)?

Comment: @Vlad it's not clear what you're asking by that... Maybe there can be multiple instances of `RKObjectMapping` and so you can set multiple mappings for the same class.

Comment: Ah sorry about the confusion. My mistake. I confused RKObjectMapping with RKObjectManager for a little bit there. I understand now and it makes sense. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Think of the singleton pattern as a way to manage a global object in an "orderly" way with the guarantee that only one of its kind be ever present in the system.

So, a singleton is just a way to get access to a global, unique object that will be instantiated on the first attempt to access it.

Once you get access to this global, unique object, it behaves exactly like any other object in your systems: it has its own state, methods, etc.

An alternative approach that the designer of RestKit might have taken could have been making `RKObjectManager` a class with only class methods and encapsulating its state through static global variables.

In this way, you would not even have the concept of instantiating the class, and could just call its methods directly. On the other hand, this is pretty a poor design decision, IMO, in Objective-C, given that language lack of support for class member variables (as opposed to, say, C++), and due to the higher refactorability of a singleton class.

Comment: No. OP does understand that the `RKObjectManager` class is being used as a singleton. He asks why a singleton is used instead of simple class methods, which 1. is not answered by your answer, 2. is a quite logical question from someone who doesn't immediately know the relation of ivars.

Comment: @H2CO2: I see, thanks for your clarification. I changed my explanation to take into account your insight.